# Critical Point Classification

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We're modeling competing species in my mathematical modeling class and we were taught the nullclines and direction arrows as a method to classify what critical points are and their stability. Usually, there are four directions arrows around each critical point that help determine whether it's a sink, a source, a saddle, or a center/spiral. But I just came across this case, where I have 6 direction arrows around one critical point and I have no idea how to go about classifying it. I tried to search online but I don't know if I'm not using the correct words or if there's just something wrong about this.

The equation system we have is

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(a-bx-ky)$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = y(c-dy-\sigma x)$

and we're told to analyze what happens when $\frac{a}{k}=\frac{c}{d}$

Here's the graph I got. I can see that $(0,0)$ is a source and $(\frac{a}{b},0)$ is a saddle.
Not sure what $(0,\frac{a}{k}=\frac{c}{d})$ is supposed to be or how to analyze it. The $\frac{dx}{dt}$ nullclines are in green, and the $\frac{dy}{dt}$ nullclines are in blue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [saddle node](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Saddle_node), a critical point that occurs only in nonlinear systems.
[image]

If the critical point is not hyperbolic, its type may not coincide with any of the types known from the linear theory classification.

The picture is drawn for parameter values $a=k=c=d=\sigma=1$, $b=2$.

Comment: thanks! So from an ecological point of view, since we only care about the positive solution, it behaves kinda like a sink?

Comment: @R.Bair Yes. $x=0$ is an invariant set, so no trajectory can traverse the $y$ axis.